# Recover missing profile in Scott Pilgrim vs The World

Tags: ps3, scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world

I had two profiles with Scott Pilgrim save data before I lost my first PS3, which I (thought I) restored to my new PS3 via a backup. However, since the Wallace update, when I go to try and play the game again I only get the option to play as the "Guest" profile, which cannot save data. My main profile (which is connected to a PSN account and owned my old play data) is not accessible at all. I created 2 new profiles and these profiles show up alongside Guest (and presumably can actually save their data).

Is there any way to allow my main account to create save data for this game again, ideally recovering the save data I seem to have lost?